# How to create another version of the Category widget?

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

I need to handle both Brands and Categories in WordPress. So I thought I would create a new copy of the Category widget – just with Brands.

I've tried various workarounds, including tags, custom fields etc. But I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve posts using multiple parameters.

So, having a widget for the categories and another for the brands, and a simple way to only retrieve posts that have both set would be what I'm trying to achieve.

I've tried using tags, adding Brands to the Categories (a mess), Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) ...

How would I go about doing this the proper way in WordPress?

COMPLETE SCENARIO DESCRIPTION OF WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:

1. I'd like to set both a category and a brand for a custom post type (product).
2. On the front end I'd like to create two separate selects (one for the Categories and another for the Brands)
3. The user make any combination of selections (all in one, and a specific in the other, or all in both ... yeah, you get it). Then click an arrow, and reload the page with the new parameters.

I've managed to fix all the creation of the selects (apart from the values of the custom fields of course, hence the question), and the url params, reload etc. I'm just stuck on the back end of things, and the retrieval of the correct posts.

I'm doing this to get a drop down of my custom post types (using wp_dropdown_pages to get custom post types, yeah talking about naming things and what they can actually do!). How would I do this for taxonomies?

```
$args_brands = array(
    'post_type' => 'brands',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'value_field' => 'brand_select', <-- GET ACTUAL CF VALUE (not some just 'some' number)?
    'select' => false,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'selected' => $brand,
    'class' => 'brands',
    'show_option_no_change' => 'All',
    'echo' => false
);

$brands_dropdown = preg_replace(
    '^' . preg_quote( '<select ' ) . '^', 
    '<select autocomplete="off" ', 
    $brands_dropdown
);

$brands_dropdown = wp_dropdown_pages( $args_brands );
echo $brands_dropdown;
```

Comment: Is "Brands" a taxonomy? A custom field? A post type? Please edit your question to include refinements.

Comment: Well, that's actually part of my question - how to do this the proper way. I've tried using tags, adding Brands to the Categories (a mess), Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) ... but I can't seem to figure out what the »proper, best, fanciest« way to do this is.

Comment: This would seem an obvious things to do in WP, but I haven't been able to google down any solution – which seem weird. Maybe I'm asking the wrong thing?

Comment: [When Do You Need a Custom Post Type or Taxonomy in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/when-do-you-need-a-custom-post-type-or-taxonomy-in-wordpress/)

Comment: @JackJohansson Well, sort of. I'm only »filtering« on an active click (don't want the page to reload every time you change one of the selects).

Comment: @MaxYudin Well, I read all I can think of about taxonomies. But how do I then retrieve them and create a select with those values on the frontend? And then get posts only with the category and the taxonomy ... I'm pretty baffled about how obscured these concepts are.

Comment: There nothing is obscured. In 10 days it will turn 7 years since custom post types and custom taxonomies were introduced. During this time these features became as well explained and documented as nothing else on WordPress because these were long-awaiting and are the most useful features when using WordPress as CMS.

Comment: But that doesn't help me in my situation ... if it's that simple, then why not provide an answer?

Comment: You have to make an attempt yourself. Then we'll be able to help. If you want somebody to write the whole code for you for free, this is not the right place to ask for it.

Comment: @MaxYudin Well, I'm only here because that's exactly what I've been trying the last 24 hours or so. Problem is, that when you get here eventually you're so damn frustrated you can hardly type ... you wouldn't want to see the amount of code I've been »trying« for the past day (and night) ...